# Compare different columns in different data frames and create new loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two data frames looking like this

```
a
   Id   start stop
1  ABC  25    30
2  ACD  40    60
3  BCD  55    60

b
   Id   start stop
1  XYZ  20    50
2  ZXY  80    90
3  YZX  50    70
```

And I want to merge the Ids in the two data frames and put them into a new (like below), if the value in the start column is higher in the first data frame and the value in the stop column is lower in the first data frame. So, as [1,2] is higher in a, than [1,2] in b and [1,3] in a is lower than [1,3], the id's [1,1] in both data frames goes into the new data frame.

```
1  ABC  XYZ
2  BCD  YZX
```

I'm trying to do this with a for loop, like below, but can't seem to get it to work as I want. Any help is appreciated. I'm also quite new to R, so please keep it simple :-)

```
a<-dataframe1
b<-dataframe2
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(b)) {
    if (a[i,2]>b[j,2] & a[i,3]<b[j,3]) {
      z<-as.data.frame(cbind(a[i,1],b[j,1]))
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your output in a better way? It is confusing now. How does output get ABC, XYZ ?

Comment: Agree with @YOLO; shouldn't the first row in output be `ACD XYZ`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `findOverlaps` from the R/Bioconductor library `GenomicRanges`:

```
library(GenomicRanges);
gr.a <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(cbind.data.frame(seqnames = 1, a), keep = T);
gr.b <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(cbind.data.frame(seqnames = 1, b), keep = T);

hits <- findOverlaps(gr.a, gr.b, type = "within");
cbind.data.frame(
    from_a = mcols(gr.a[queryHits(hits)])$Id,
    from_b = mcols(gr.b[subjectHits(hits)])$Id)
#  from_a from_b
#1    ABC    XYZ
#2    BCD    YZX
```

A note: I use `GenomicRanges` here because of its diverse interval operations; it seems that the R library `intervals` offers similar functionality.

---

### Sample data

```
a <- read.table(text =
    "Id   start stop
1  ABC  25    30
2  ACD  40    60
3  BCD  55    60", header = T, row.names = 1)

b <- read.table(text =
   "Id   start stop
1  XYZ  20    50
2  ZXY  80    90
3  YZX  50    70", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `data.table` can be achieved as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)
setDT(b)

a[b, .(Id_a = Id, Id_b = i.Id), on=.(start>=start , stop<=stop), nomatch = 0]
# Id_a Id_b
# 1:  ABC  XYZ
# 2:  BCD  YZX
```

**Option#2:** using library `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT a.ID as Id_a, b.ID as Id_b 
       FROM a, b
       WHERE a.start >= b.start AND a.stop <= b.stop")
#    Id_a Id_b
# 1  ABC  XYZ
# 2  BCD  YZX
```

**Data**

```
a <- read.table(text = 
"Id   start stop
ABC  25    30
ACD  40    60
BCD  55    60",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b <- read.table(text = 
"Id   start stop
XYZ  20    50
ZXY  80    90
YZX  50    70",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```